# Maximum skewness portfolio solution derived from its Lagrangean formulation

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, mean-variance, skewness, moments

$$\arg \min_w \quad w^\top \Sigma w$$
\begin{align}\text{s.t.} \quad \mathbf{1}^\top w = 1 \end{align}
is the optimization problem for the **minimum-variance portfolio** weights, whose analytical solution, derived from the above's Lagrangean formulation, is
$$w_{MV}=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^T\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{1}}$$

The **max skewness portfolio**, on the other hand, where $M_3$ is the coskewness matrix, has the optimization problem
$$\arg \min_w \quad -w^\top M_3 (w\otimes w)$$
\begin{align}\text{s.t.} \quad \mathbf{1}^\top w = 1 \end{align}

What then is the closed-form solution of the above's Lagrangean formula (not shown here)? How can the weights be derived analytically
$$w_{SK}=?$$

Comment: On second thought, I would like to add that the *portfolio skewness* is defined as third moment divided by $\sigma_P^{1.5}$, i.e. it is a normalised quantity.

Comment: which source shows this normalization for portfolios? I have never seen it as a denominator for the portfolio skewness objective function

Comment: Simply look up the definition of skewness. Just saying...

Comment: but the definition of non-portfolio skewness doesn't possess portfolio weight multipliers. to now say that there is a denominator for portfolio skewness renders every previous publication on portfolio skewness invalid

Comment: Hold your horses. Skew is defined as $\frac{M_3}{M_2^{1.5}}$, i.e. the normalised third central moment. During optimisation, you can **of course** maximize portfolio $M_3$, only. Nothing stops you from that. But if you do not normalise this expression you may arrive at strange results. You can **literally** see for yourself in a two-asset portfolio with weights $w,1-w$, some (co-)skewness parameters and unit variances.

Comment: all horses held, I am sure your reasoning is fully qualified, but its all the other previous publications I am glowering at. How could they have knowingly made such an ommission

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there exist no closed form for this.

The Lagrangean reads

$$
L(w,\lambda)=w^TM_3(w\otimes w)-\lambda(w^T\mathbf{1}-1)
$$

with first order conditions

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L }{\partial w_i}&=3w^TM_{3,i}w-\lambda \quad \forall i \\
\frac{\partial L }{\partial \lambda}&=w^T\mathbf{1}-1
\end{align}
$$

where $M_{3,i}$ is the $i$th matrix component of the $3$-dimensional skewness tensor. The derivative of $w^TM_3(w\otimes w)$ with respect to $w_i$ is easily verified algebraically, and comparison to a quadratic form.

Effectively, this is a system of **quadratic forms**:

$$
\begin{align}
w^TM_{3,1}w&=\lambda\\
w^TM_{3,2}w&=\lambda\\
\ldots&=\lambda\\
w^TM_{3,N}w&=\lambda\\
w^T\mathbf{1}&=1
\end{align}
$$
There exist no closed-form solution for this. You could try to solve this equation system using a multivariate Newton Raphson scheme and careful selection of starting values.

---

Answering your comment:

> .... Since there is no closed-form solution for the max skewness portfolio, does that mean that we cannot derive a proof that the max skewness portfolio has higher skewness than the most skewed asset?

At least anecdotically, it is quite easy to show that for a two-asset portfolio, the *boundedness* of the portfolio skewness is driven by the level of the *co-skewness*.

Please find below two graphs for a two asset portfolio. In each case, the assets of unit variance, no covariance, and skewness of $S_{111}=0.05$, $S_{222}=-0.05$. In the first graph, the co-skews $S_{112}=S_{122}=0.0$, in the second graph they are $+0.1$ and $-0.1$, respectively. The $x$-axis shows the portfolio weight on asset 1.

[image: No co-skewness]
[image: With co-skewness]

As you can see, the question whether or not portfolio skew is bounded by the asset skews is driven by **co-skewness*. Again, diversification is the key.

HTH?

Comment: In the other post, you used the closed-form solution of the minimum-variance portfolio to prove that the **minimum-variance portfolio** has lower variance than the **lowest variance asset**. Since there is no closed-form solution for the max skewness portfolio, does that mean that we cannot derive a proof that the **max skewness portfolio** has higher skewness than the **most skewed asset**?

Comment: @develarist I have updated my post on this. HTH?

Comment: thanks for the edits. I guess the figures say that asset skewness forms bounds on portfolio skewness only if there is no coskewness, and that portfolio skewness only outperforms asset skewness if coskewness is non-zero (although getting the direction of "over-"skewness right is futile). I wonder how well these two laws both generalize to the case where there are more than 2 assets. Is there a source that similarly demonstrates the skewness-portfolio weight analysis you have shown?